# cloneNode inconsistent with namespaces - cross environments?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

When attempting to clone a DOMNode object (DOMNode::cloneNode) I am experiencing inconsistencies running it across different environments, specifically with the clone failing to copy the namespace when I print the nodeName property, e.g.

```
$cloneNode = $origNode->cloneNode(true);
echo("old node name = " . $origNode->nodeName);
echo("new node name = " . $cloneNode->nodeName);
```

**result (local - mac os)** 
"old node name = namespace:Hello"
"new node name = namespace:Hello"

**result (local - centos)**:
"old node name = namespace:Hello"
"new node name = Hello"

I register the namespace with DOMXPath::registerNamespace prior to doing anything with nodes.

#### Update

I've found the offending line ($origNode->parentNode->removeChild( $origNode );) that when removed causes the clone to work as expected, regardless. Keeping said line in however still yields different results cross environment. An example:

```
<?php

$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Root xmlns:ns="http://google.com/">
    <ns:Hello>
        <ns:World/>
    </ns:Hello>
</ns:Root>';

$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($string);


$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
$rootNamespace = $dom->documentElement->lookupNamespaceUri('ns');
$xpath->registerNamespace('ns', $rootNamespace);


$parentNode = $xpath->query('//ns:Hello')->item( 0 );
$origNode = $xpath->query('//ns:World')->item( 0 );
$origNode->parentNode->removeChild($origNode);

$newNode = $origNode->cloneNode( true );

echo("old node name = " . $origNode->nodeName) . PHP_EOL;
echo("new node name = " . $newNode->nodeName) . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Comment: Don't namespaces apply to documents instead of nodes? I may be way off here.

Comment: Can you provide a small piece of reproducible code? What PHP versions are you using?

Comment: mac 5.4, centos 5.3 - I've also ran the test on another mac on 5.3, and worked regardless.

Comment: also compare libxml versions. that will likely show a difference. http://php.net/libxml.constants

Comment: good shout, this has revealed they are running different versions, will update centos box and see if this results in the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved - the different behavior was the result of different versions of libxml (20706 vs 20708). After updating the centos box to 20708 the namespace persisted as expected.